# In California, do people still get benefits if they got terminated earlier than the date that they gave?

Tags: employment, california

For example, Sam gives notice to his boss, saying that he is moving out California soon, so Sam decided not to come to work after 2 weeks. After that notice, his boss started finding people fit Sam's position.
After 13 days, one day earlier than 2 week, his boss told Sam that day is his last day at the end of work. ADDED(Sam have not done any thing wrong, from Sam's knowledge: his boss just doesn't want to pay extra day of salary since a new person is found for Sam's position.)

Q. Is Sam still cover by Unemployment Benefits, Severance Pay?

Answer (score 2):

Sam is not entitled to unemployment benefits because it is a voluntary quit.

*There's an exception where a person can argue that even though it looked like a voluntary quit, it really wasn't. The person might have learned they were about to lay off everyone in the state (and then that happened). Or been told "Please turn in your resignation by the end of the day", a common executive courtesy allowing you to save face. Since those aren't really voluntary quits, the employment office will accept them as layoffs.* *

So the way I see it, that sword cuts both ways. If a layoff is viewed as a *fait accompli* even if there's a resignation a few days prior.... then a voluntary resignation is a *fait accompli* even if there's a layoff a day prior.

In fact it is very common for employers to say "Thanks for the 2 weeks notice. Go pack your stuff, today is your last day in the office" (sometimes with a guard watching you pack your stuff and walk out the door).  The remaining 2 weeks are either a gift from the employer, or come out of your accumulated sick or vacation time.   At workaholic IBM this often amounted to *months* - "I'm quitting as of May 2. My last day in the office will be December 30."

* However, if Sam's behavior met the unemployment office's definition of "fired for cause", e.g. stealing, then Sam is not eligible for unemployment.

Comment: I know this is a different question, and may not even law related, 
What is the best way to quit a job while protecting one's interest ?

Comment: @mmmmmmmmmmmmm that is off topic here, ask on workplace.SE

Comment: It's possible he's entitled to it for the day.